# How to set a tablet device dimensions on a web browser

Tags: android, flutter, responsive-design, frontend, tablet

I am using flutter for developing an android app optimised (from frontend layout perspective) for a specific tablet (Galaxy tab A8).

Specs for tablet are -
Resolution: 1920x1080, 16:10 ratio (216 ppi density)
Dimensions: 9.72 inches x 6.37 inches

The issue is that I do not have the tablet physically and my machine is too low powered to run an emulator hence I need to rely on the chrome/web for development.

Now when I try to use the chrome dev tools and and plug in the resolution in the responsive settings, the screen I get has way more space than the actual device and hence I am not able to optimise specifically for that device.

I think the device dimensions has something to do with this issue but there is no option to set the dimensions for the browser window. How do I set the resolution in chrome dev tool so that it matches my device. Is there any conversion factor?

Comment: Note: Software recommendation questions are off-topic for reasons explained in #3 of [/help/on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Could you please remove your request for alternate tool recommendations?